# Delay an angular.js $http service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have some angular factories for making ajax calls towards legacy ASP.NET .asmx web services like so:

```
module.factory('productService', ["$http",
function ($http) {
    return {
        getSpecialProducts: function (data) {
            return $http.post('/ajax/Products.asmx/GetSpecialProducs', data);
        }
    }
} ]);
```

I'm testing on a local network so response times are "too" good. Is there a smart way of delaying the $http a couple of seconds from making the call to simulate a bad connection?

Or do I need to wrap all calls to the factory methods in a $timeout ?

```
$timeout(function() {
  productService.getSpecialProducs(data).success(success).error(error);
}, $scope.MOCK_ajaxDelay);
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Interesting question!

As you mentioned yourself, `$timeout` is the most logical choice for a delayed call. Instead of having `$timeout` calls everywhere, you could push a response interceptor that wraps the `$http`  promise in a `$timeout` promise, as conceptually outlined in the [documentation of `$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), and register it in one of your configuration blocks. This means all `$http` calls are affected by the `$timeout` delay. Something along the lines of:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($timeout) {
    return {
        "response": function (response) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                return response;
            }, 2500);
        }
    };
});
```

As a bonus to your "to simulate a bad connection?", you could reject or do absolutely nothing randomly, too. *Heh heh heh.*

Comment: Beats my answer! - Seems I need to do some reading on interceptors

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if the server returns an error (i.e. anything non 2XX). You need to add the error function and reject it in that case as well.

Comment: @cdmckay of course you would handle the fail of the response, but that is not part of the question ;-).

Comment: Where is the best place to put that in, the run or the config phase? Okay I answer myself: you can't put $q and $timeout inside the config-phase. Mhm realy? I give up...

Comment: The syntax has changed in the newer AngularJS versions. The new syntax is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31873453/232649

Comment: I updated the syntax! Feel free to edit answers when the syntax is outdated.

Comment: @stevuu I removed the unnecessary usage of `$q`. `$timeout` and other similar services return a promise that is resolved with the return value of the function, so it's not necessary to create a promise manually.

Answer (score 17):

The new chrome device emulator has a network throttling function:

[image]

To get there: In Google Chrome, press F12 to open the Developer Tools. Then, on the top left corner, click the "Toggle device mode" icon (left to the "Elements" menu).

Comment: In my Chrome I found the dropdown for throttling on the Network tab.  No need to activate device emulator.

Comment: Problem is this doesn't work if you are mocking data and not actually making the network calls

Answer (score 4):

Developing more on the answer of @stevuu

`responseInterceptors` seems to be depreceted (as of 1.2.20) I have modified the code to work on the `interceptors` mechanism:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                        defer.resolve(response);
                }, 2300);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the $q service for defer().promise pattern:

```
function someFunction(MOCK_ajaxDelay) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.post('/ajax/Products.asmx/GetSpecialProducs', data).success(function(response) {
      $timeout(function() {deferred.resolve({ success: true, response: response })}, MOCK_ajaxDelay);  
   }).error(function() {
      $timeout(function() {deferred.resolve({ success: true, response: response } }, MOCK_ajaxDelay);  
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}

someService.someFunction(500).then(function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
      $scope.items = data.response.d;
    }
});
```

But if you are really mock testing, the better solution is to look into ngMock: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend

Answer (score 2):

While [@stevuu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238708/232649) answer is correct, the syntax has changed in the newer AngularJS versions since then. The updated syntax is:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(["$q", "$timeout", function ($q, $timeout) {
  function slower(response) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return {
    'response': slower
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the promise api combined with a $timeout. The $http.post function returns a promise from which you can call .success and .error (these are http specific methods). This promise is *resolved* when the http request is complete. If you build your own promise then you can tell it to delay 2 seconds and then resolve when the http request is complete:

```
module.factory('productService', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {

    return {
        getSpecialProducts: function (data) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/ajax/Products.asmx/GetSpecialProducs', data).success(
              function(data) {
                // successful http request, resolve after two seconds
                $timeout(function() {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }, 2000)
            }).error(function() {
                defer.reject("Http Error");
            })
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

But note - you will have to use `promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` functionality - that is, you'll lose the ability to access http headers, status & config from your controllers/directives unless you explicitly supply them to the object passed to `defer.resolve({})`

Links:

- [Defer/Promise Api](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24q)
- [Http/Promise Api](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24http)
- [Resolve egghead video](http://www.egghead.io/video/Kr1qZ8Ik9G8)

Answer (score 0):

In response to the testing aspect of your question, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) has a really useful function that helps when you need to simulate delays:

1. Click on the AutoResponders tab in Fiddler.
2. Add a rule with a regex that matches the URL of the request you want to delay.
3. Set the "respond with" to "*delay:1000" where the number is the delay in milliseconds.

The AutoResponder functionality in Fiddler is extremely useful for testing JS that involves a lot of http requests. You can set it to respond with particular http error codes, block responses, etc.

Comment: I've assumed that you are using Windows because of the use of a asp.net web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a service that returns a promise, then inside you should put a **return** before the **$timeout** as well because that returns just another promise.

```
return dataService.loadSavedItem({
    save_id: item.save_id,
    context: item.context
}).then(function (data) {
    // timeout returns a promise
    return $timeout(function () {
        return data;
    },2000);
});
```

Hope it helps someone!